# Can I pass Soft Assert object as a method parameter?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, assert

The existing Framework is designed in the below way. We assert a few checks in the VerifyAttributes. Question is I want to change the Assert to soft Assert so the test does not stop on failure of a single Assertion and the test continues.
How can I use a single soft assertion object for all of the checks? Can I create a soft assert in the parent class within the test and pass it as an attribute when calling the methods?

```
public class TestClass extends BaseTest {

@Test(description="test to verify if the keyboard and mouse attributes are generated)
public void testKeyboardMouseAttributes(String os, String browser, String device){
//User performs some keyboard and mouse actions
InterfaceToVerifyAttributes verifyAttr = new InterfaceToVerifyAttributes("testKeyboardMouseAttributes",os,browser,device);
verifyAttr.keyboardAttributes();
}
}

public class InterfaceToVerifyAttributes {
    private String os, browser, device, testcase;
    public InterfaceToVerifyAttributes(String tc, String os, String browser, String device) {
        this.os = os;
        this.browser = browser;
        this.device = device;
        this.testcase=tc;
    }
public void keyboardAttributes(){
VerifyAttributes verifyAttr = new VerifyAttributes(testcase, os, browser, device);
        verifyAttr.verifyUnknownSession(false);
        verifyAttr.keyboardAttributes();
}}

public class VerifyAttributes{
private String os, browser, device, orgId;
//getters and setters

public void verifyUnknownSession(boolean expected) {
            Assert.assertNotNull(api.getSpecifiedParameter("unknown_session"),
                    " ** should be unknown session ** " + testcase + " " + os + " " + browser + " org_id " + orgId);
}
public void verifyKeyboardPageElements() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(//attribute is present);
Assert.assertTrue(//attribute value is equal to something);
//A few other assertions
      }
public void verifyMouseElements() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(//attribute is present);
Assert.assertTrue(//attribute value is equal to something);
//A few other assertions
      }
public void verifyPasswordType() { //This method is not used but is present
        Assert.assertNotNull(//attribute is present);
Assert.assertTrue(//attribute value is equal to something);
//A few other assertions
      }

}
```

Comment: Are you using TestNG or JUnit or ? I would look at their docs and see if they either have one or you can extend something.

Comment: We use TestNG. I made a correction. The Class having the test extends a Basetest class.
My question is how can I use Soft Assert when we have Asserts spread across multiple methods thats in other class. Can I create a SoftAssert obj in the test class and pass it as a parameter when calling the methods to verify? 
Is this a good way of doing the check or if there is a better way of handling it

Comment: There's a lot of existing documentation on how to implement soft asserts in TestNG. I would suggest you do some googling and reading and find the method that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this

```
public class TestClass extends BaseTest {

@Test(description="test to verify if the keyboard and mouse attributes are generated)
public void testKeyboardMouseAttributes(String os, String browser, String device){
SoftAssert sftp = new SoftAssert();
//User performs some keyboard and mouse actions
InterfaceToVerifyAttributes verifyAttr = new InterfaceToVerifyAttributes(os,browser,device,sftp);
sftp = verifyAttr.keyboardAttributes(sftp);
}
sftp.assertAll();
}

public class InterfaceToVerifyAttributes {
    private String os, browser, device;
SoftAssert sftp;
    public InterfaceToVerifyAttributes(String os, String browser, String device, SoftAssert sftp) {
        this.os = os;
        this.browser = browser;
        this.device = device;
        this.sftp = sftp;
    }
public SoftAssert keyboardAttributes(SoftAssert sftp){
VerifyAttributes verifyAttr = new VerifyAttributes( os, browser, device, sftp);
        sftp = verifyAttr.verifyUnknownSession(sftp);

}

return sftp;
}

public class VerifyAttributes{
private String os, browser, device;
SoftAssert sftp;

 public VerifyAttributes(String os, String browser, String device, SoftAssert sftp) {
        this.os = os;
        this.browser = browser;
        this.device = device;
        this.sftp = sftp;
}

public SoftAssert verifyUnknownSession(SoftAssert sftp) {
            sftp.assertNotNull(api.getSpecifiedParameter("unknown_session"),
                    " ** should be unknown session ** " + os + " " + browser);
}

return sftp;
}
```

Comment: To build on this, I have now used AssertJ. On a test case failure, this lists the assertions that failed and also points to the exact failure that caused the assertion failure.